# Ubuntu 20.04 | App to make live ISO?

Tags: system-installation, software-recommendation, 20.04, iso

I need an application similar to Pinguy Builder (which creates an installable ISO image of your current system) that works on Ubuntu 20.04

If there isn't one, is it possible to downgrade, make the ISO, install, and then reupgrade?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did not you check CUBIC??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to customize the Ubuntu Live CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd)

Answer (score 0):

Pinguy Builder Menu Based 5.2.1 dist mode works after making changes in pinguy conf file in the folder /usr/bin. For me it worked of Linux Mint 20 Cinnamon.

```bsh
#Cleaning Apt and backing up
# find /etc/apt -type f -iname \*.save -delete &> /dev/null
# find /etc/apt -type f -iname \*~ -delete &> /dev/null
 tar pczvf /root/apt.tar.gz /etc/apt &> /dev/null
 sed -i "s/deb/#deb/g" /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
 sed -i "s/deb/#deb/g" /etc/apt/sources.list
 echo "$SOURCESLIST" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
 apt-get update  &> /dev/null
.
.
.

if [ "`ps axf | grep startkde | grep -v grep`" != "" -o "`ps axf | grep kwin | grep -v grep`" != "" ]; then
        log_msg "Installing the Ubiquity KDE frontend"
    #   apt-get -y -q purge ubiquity-casper &> /dev/null
    #   apt-get -y -q purge ubiquity &> /dev/null
    #   apt-get -y -q remove ubiquity-ubuntu-artwork &> /dev/null
        apt-get -y -q remove ubiquity-frontend-kde &> /dev/null
        apt-get -y -q install ubiquity-frontend-kde &> /dev/null
        apt-get -y -q remove ubiquity-frontend-gtk &> /dev/null
        chmod +x /usr/share/applications/kde4/ubiquity-kdeui.desktop &> /dev/null
        sed -i "s/ubiquity kde_ui/pkexec ubiquity kde_ui/" /usr/share/applications/kde4/ubiquity-kdeui.desktop
    else
        log_msg "Installing the Ubiquity GTK frontend"
     #  apt-get -y -q purge ubiquity-casper &> /dev/null
     #  apt-get -y -q purge ubiquity &> /dev/null
     #  apt-get -y -q remove ubiquity-ubuntu-artwork &> /dev/null
        apt-get -y -q remove ubiquity-frontend-gtk &> /dev/null
        apt-get -y -q install ubiquity-frontend-gtk &> /dev/null
        apt-get -y -q remove ubiquity-frontend-kde &> /dev/null
        chmod +x /usr/share/applications/ubiquity.desktop &> /dev/null
        sed -i "s/sh -c 'ubiquity

    # Replacing Ubiquity icons
    cp -a /etc/PinguyBuilder/icons /usr/share/
    chmod 775 -R /usr/share/icons
    rm -rf /usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/ubuntu-logo-icon.png
    ln -s /usr/share/icons/ubuntu-logo-icon.png /usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps
    chmod 777 /usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/ubuntu-logo-icon.png
    chmod 777 /usr/share/icons/ubuntu-logo-icon.png
    gtk-update-icon-cache
    update-icon-caches /usr/share/icons/*
#   rm -r /etc/apt &> /dev/null
#   tar -xf /root/apt.tar.gz -C / &> /dev/null
```

Comment: Linux mint is off topic here, as it is not Ubuntu.

Comment: It Works for ubuntu 20.04 too